# To prove $\dim(W)=n$ for $W=\{{p\in V :\int_0^1p(x)dx=0}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials over $\Bbb R$ of degree atmost $n$,where $n\ge2$.
>   Considering elements of $V$ as functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$,define
>
> $$W=\{{p\in V :\int_0^1p(x)dx=0}\}$$
>   Show that $\dim(W)=n$

I'm getting no clue as to how to prove this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the transformation $T:V \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$T(p(x))=\int_0^1 p(x) \, dx.$$
This is a linear transformation whose kernel is $W$. Now use rank nullity theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach :

Take $p(x)\in W\implies \int _0^1 p(x)\text{dx}=0$.

If $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots +a_nx^n,\int _0^1 p(x)=0\implies a_0+\frac{a_1}{2}+\frac{a_2}{3}+\ldots +\frac{a_n}{n+1}=0$

So $W=\{p(x)\in V:a_0+\frac{a_1}{2}+\frac{a_2}{3}+\ldots +\frac{a_n}{n+1}=0\}$

Since $\dim V=n+1\implies \dim W=n$